# JMeter 3.0 Distributed--How to count JSON key/value Occurrences per minute?

Tags: json, jmeter

I've read quite a bit but can't find the basics of incorporating scripting into HTTP Request API JMeter Scripts.

I use JMeter in distributed test mode.  One of my test cases verifies a throttling limit whereby the JSON response contains (or not) a particular value.

For example, if access to a limited supply of tickets for sale is being throttled, the response JSON contains, `"command" : "buyTicket"`, until the limit for that interval is met.  Once the limit is met, response JSON would not contain that key/value.

I need to know (tabular, or timeline) how many return JSON messages contained that key/value per minute across all slaves. My research (Regular Expression Extractor, jp#gc - JSON Path Extractor) hasn't show how to attach time-stamps or aggregation of data in the distributed mode.

If I can script JMeter to write the results (specified key/value pair per min) to an external file (Simple Data Writer), that would be fine. If I could graph it with JMeter that would be great.

Comment: Do you want to count the `contains` and display its time stamp? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam: Please do not add useless fluff like "Please check and approve" in edit summaries. That's the entire job of the edit reviewers (that and rejecting). Just describe what the edit does in a way that's quicker to understand than looking at the red and green changes.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yes I do add the brief note about the edit. I will not add that phrase again. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Sample Variables property](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables), this way you can add your `command` value into JMeter .jtl results file. JMeter .jtl result files naturally contain timestamps so you will be able to plot the values using your favourite tool.

- Assuming that you store your `key/value` (whatever it is ) into a JMeter Variable called `${foo}`
- Add the next line to *user.properties* file on all JMeter instances:

  ```
  sample_variables=foo
  ```
- Run your test
- You will be able to see your `${foo}` variable value as the last column in .jtl results file:

  [image]

Amending the property in *user.properties* file requires JMeter restart, if you want to add property or change an existing property value only once you can do it via -J command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jsample_variables=foo -n -t ...
```

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

---

I would also recommend upgrading to latest JMeter version (3.2 as of now)